# topic_tools is not working

Tags: ros, topic-tools

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi all,
I want to use topic_tools to have a RPY representation of Quaternions.
I installed the package but it semms that topic_tools does not contain the transform package.
I have Hydro + Ubuntu 12.04

http://wiki.ros.org/topic_tools

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/199223/topic_tools-is-not-working/) by [mark_vision](https://answers.ros.org/users/11321/mark_vision/) on ROS Answers with karma: 275 on 2014-12-10

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Wolf](https://answers.ros.org/users/4478/wolf/) on 2014-12-10**:
Could you plz state what is not working (error message, command you attempted to run, or something)...

**Comment by [mark_vision](https://answers.ros.org/users/11321/mark_vision/) on 2014-12-10**:
The error is just there's no executable. So if I run `rosrun topic_tools transform <some parameters>` it says could not find executable. The list of executables include : `mux_<something>`, `relay`, `throttle` and `drop`

**Comment by [Wolf](https://answers.ros.org/users/4478/wolf/) on 2014-12-10**:
Ok, just checked, the issue is valid for my system, too;) running hydro on Ubuntu 12.04; no "transform" executable in the anywhere ros installation folder /opt/ros/hydro while throttle, mux, relay etc. are there in /opt/ros/hydro/lib/topic_tools folder

**Comment by [jarvisschultz](https://answers.ros.org/users/1272/jarvisschultz/) on 2014-12-10**:
It appears the transform tool was added in commit [ede12dbb](https://github.com/ros/ros_comm/commit/ede12dbb4fd353e8ef4f62d95d1e0c2aa42526c6) on the `indigo-devel` branch. You could try building the `indigo-devel` branch of `ros_comm` in your workspace to try and add this functionality to Hydro.

**Comment by [Wolf](https://answers.ros.org/users/4478/wolf/) on 2014-12-11**:
Ok, is it then correct that transform is still shown in the wiki, even if I switch to hydro doc (http://wiki.ros.org/topic_tools)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

As @jarvisschultz stated in the comment transform tool was first added to the indigo-devel branch, therefore is not available under ROS hydro and previous versions....

---

Originally posted by [Wolf](https://answers.ros.org/users/4478/wolf/) with karma: 7555 on 2014-12-11

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [mark_vision](https://answers.ros.org/users/11321/mark_vision/) on 2015-01-12**:
Then, whoever has the power to change the page, please remove the wrong switches